# Post Data to Microsoft Graph with Python

Tags: python, azure, graph

I want to post Data to the Microsoft Graph API.
I have already a Graph Client for this:

```
def initialize_graph_for_user_auth(config):
     this.settings = config
     client_id = this.settings['clientId']
     tenant_id = this.settings['authTenant']
     graph_scopes = this.settings['graphUserScopes'].split(' ')
     this.device_code_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id, 
     tenant_id = tenant_id)
     this.user_client = 
     GraphClient(credential=this.device_code_credential, 
     scopes=graph_scopes)
```

Now I want to add a user to a Azure Group. I have the correct User ID and Group ID when I call this.

```
def add_member_to_group(user_id, group_id):
ensure_graph_for_app_only_auth()`
payload = {'@odata.id': 
f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}'}
response = this.app_client.groups[group_id].post(data=payload)
if response.status_code == 204:
    print(f'Successfully added user {user_id} to group 
    {group_id}.')`
else:
    print('Error:', response.content)
```

Comment: The graph tag is irrelevant.  Does anyone read the tag descriptions before slapping them onto their questions?

Answer (score 1):

To add a user to an Azure group using the Microsoft Graph API, you can use the following code:

```
from msgraphcore import GraphSession
from msgraphcore.middleware import AuthenticationProviderMiddleware

def add_member_to_group(user_id, group_id):
    graph_session = GraphSession(AuthenticationProviderMiddleware(
    tDeviceCodeAuthProvider(client_id, tenant_id)))
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/$ref"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {"@odata.id": f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}"}
    response = graph_session.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f'Successfully added user {user_id} to group {group_id}.')
    else:
        print('Error:', response.content)
```

Comment: I get the error message: Error: b'{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list.","innerError":{"date":"2023-03-09T08:38:42","request-id":"<id>","client-request-id":"<iD>"}}}'

Comment: The error message indicates that the group you are trying to add a user to is a mail-enabled security group or distribution list. These types of groups cannot be updated using the Microsoft Graph API.
To resolve this error, you can either create a new group that is not mail-enabled and add the user to that group, or you can update the group type to a security group using the Azure Portal or PowerShell before adding the user.

Comment: is it possible to update the group type in python?

Comment: No, i don't think so